# javascript extract objects from nested arrays using a list of ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I have a list of ids as reference, and I have an object which contains multiple objects that have array of objects.

I want to make an array of objects with corresponding ids in the list, the FASTEST way.

```js
const data = {
  "items": {
    "item1": [{
        "id": "id1",
        "info": "info1"
      },
      {
        "id": "id2",
        "info": "info22"
      }
    ],
    "item20": [{
      "id": "id3",
      "info": "info5"
    }],
    "item5": [{
        "id": "id4",
        "info": "info6"
      },
      {
        "id": "id5",
        "info": "info7"
      }
    ]
  }
};

const keep = ['id4', 'id2'];
const results = [];
keep.forEach(function(val) {

  const match = Object.keys(data.items).map(item => {
    return data.items[item].find(obj => obj.id === val)
  });
  results.push(match)
})
console.log('final: ', results)
```

the current is not returning what i want.
the expected result will be:

```
[
    {
      "id": "id2",
      "info": "info22"
    },
    {
        "id": "id4",
        "info": "info6"
    }
]
```

### update:

How about in the case if the data is itself an array of objects, and we want to do the same for each one?

```js
    const data = [{
      "otherStuff": "otherB",
      "items": {
        "item1": [{
            "id": "id1",
            "info": "info1"
          },
          {
            "id": "id2",
            "info": "info22"
          }
        ],
        "item20": [{
          "id": "id3",
          "info": "info5"
        }],
        "item5": [{
            "id": "id4",
            "info": "info6"
          },
          {
            "id": "id5",
            "info": "info7"
          }
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "otherStuff": "otherA",
      "items": {
        "item1": [{
            "id": "id1",
            "info": "info10000"
          },
          {
            "id": "id2",
            "info": "info220000"
          }
        ],
        "item20": [{
          "id": "id3",
          "info": "info5000"
        }],
        "item5": [{
            "id": "id4",
            "info": "info60000"
          },
          {
            "id": "id5",
            "info": "info7000"
          }
        ]
      }
    }];


const keep = ['id4', 'id2'];
const results = [];

    keep.forEach(function(val) {
      data.forEach(function(entry){
          Object.keys(entry.items).forEach(item => {
            var match = entry.items[item].find(obj => obj.id === val);
            if (match) {
              results.push(match)
            }
          });
      });
    })
    
    console.log(results)
```

and the output should be:

```
[
    {
        "otherStuff": "otherB",
        "items": [
                {
                      "id": "id2",
                      "info": "info22"
                },
                {
                    "id": "id4",
                    "info": "info6"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "otherStuff": "otherA",
        "items": [
                {
                      "id": "id2",
                      "info": "info220000"
                },
                {
                    "id": "id4",
                    "info": "info60000"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

the result is not the same though.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: @mplungjan fixed the typo in equal sign... i need an authoratitive answer to see what is the fastest way to do it.

Comment: That is off topic here. Codereview perhaps

Comment: @mplungjan ok close it plz, gonna move it to codereview

Comment: @mplungjan No! _"the current is not returning what i want"_ means the code is not working as expected which is one close reason on Code Review.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger True - I assume he fixed that before moving the "How do I do this the fastest"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a Set for the kept ids, you save one O(n) traversal:

```
 const keep = new Set(['id4', 'id2']);

 const result = [];

 for(const items of Object.values(data.items))
   for(const item of items)
     if(keep.has(item.id))
       result.push(item);
```

Comment: Not come across `array.has` can't find any documentation either.

Comment: Ah, [Set.prototype.has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `map()`. Simply use `forEach()` loop on the object keys which you want to keep and find the matching object so that it can be pushed into the result array.

```js
const data = {
  "items": {
    "item1": [{
        "id": "id1",
        "info": "info1"
      },
      {
        "id": "id2",
        "info": "info22"
      }
    ],
    "item20": [{
      "id": "id3",
      "info": "info5"
    }],
    "item5": [{
        "id": "id4",
        "info": "info6"
      },
      {
        "id": "id5",
        "info": "info7"
      }
    ]
  }
};

const keep = ['id4', 'id2'];
const results = [];
keep.forEach(function(val) {
  Object.keys(data.items).forEach(item => {
    var match = data.items[item].find(obj => obj.id === val);
    if (match) {
      results.push(match)
    }
  });
})
console.log('final: ', results)
```

Comment: is this the fastest way to do it? filter/find/reduce/ can't they be faster?

Comment: @storis you have array of objects inside the object which will surely have `O(n2)` complexity

Comment: i updated the question with an annex, could you please have a look at it? how can I achieve the similar results in this case?

Answer (score 1):

items is an object & `item1`,`item20` are are keys.So you can do `Object.values` and apply reduce function on it to get a single array which is consist of all the objects. No iterate the `keep` array and filter out the required element from the single array.

```js
const data = {
  "items": {
    "item1": [{
        "id": "id1",
        "info": "info1"
      },
      {
        "id": "id2",
        "info": "info22"
      }
    ],
    "item20": [{
      "id": "id3",
      "info": "info5"
    }],
    "item5": [{
        "id": "id4",
        "info": "info6"
      },
      {
        "id": "id5",
        "info": "info7"
      }
    ]
  }
};



const keep = ['id4', 'id2'];
let getAllObjectValues = Object.values(data.items).reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  curr.forEach((elem) => {
    acc.push(elem)
  })
  return acc;
}, []);

let k = keep.map(function(item) {
  return getAllObjectValues.filter(function(val) {
    return item === val.id
  })[0]

})
console.log(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used an assignment operator rather than an equivalence operator in your map function, change to:

```
const keep = ['id4', 'id2'];
const results = [];
keep.forEach(function(val){
    const match = Object.keys(data.items).map(item => {
        return data.items[item].find(obj => obj.id === val)
    });
    results.push(match)
})
console.log('final: ', results)
```

Comment: No  longer a typo-type question but still off topic

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of `reduce` and `filter` you can iterate each sub-array checking whether the value should be kept.

```js
const data = {
  "items": {
    "item1": [
      {
        "id": "id1",
        "info": "info1"
      },
      {
        "id": "id2",
        "info": "info22"
      }
    ],
    "item20": [
      {
        "id": "id3",
        "info": "info5"
      }
    ],
    "item5": [
      {
        "id": "id4",
        "info": "info6"
      },
      {
        "id": "id5",
        "info": "info7"
      }
    ]
  }
};

const keep = ['id4', 'id2'];
const filter = el => {
  return keep.indexOf(el.id) >= 0;
};

const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => { 
  return accumulator = accumulator.concat(data.items[currentValue].filter(filter));
};

let results = Object.keys(data.items).reduce(reducer, []);

console.log('final: ', results);
```